# trying to take a set of data and list it in a file

Tags: python

I am having difficulty taking a set of numbers that have come from a loop and writing them to separate lines in a file. The code I have now will print 5 lines of the exact same data when what i want is the data from each line of the loop. I hope that makes sense.

```
    mass_of_rider_kg = float(input('input mass of rider in kilograms:'))
mass_of_bike_kg = float(input('input mass of bike in kilograms:'))
velocity_in_ms = float(input('input velocity in meters per second:'))
coefficient_of_drafting = float(input('input coefficient of drafting:'))


a = mass_of_rider_kg
while a < mass_of_rider_kg+20:
    a = a + 4
    pAir = .18*coefficient_of_drafting*(velocity_in_ms**3)  
    pRoll = .001*9.8*(a+mass_of_bike_kg)*velocity_in_ms
    pSec = pAir+pRoll
    print(pSec)
    myfile=open('BikeOutput.txt','w')
    for x in range(1,6):
        myfile.write('data:' + str(a) + str(mass_of_bike_kg) + str(velocity_in_ms) + str(coefficient_of_drafting) + str(pSec) + "\n")
    myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm - A number of small errors in your code -

1st opening a file with "w" in a while loop and closing it - is not a good idea if you really want to write a line corresponding to each iteration to the file. May be w+ flag would do. But again too expensive to open and close inside for loop.

A simple strategy would be -

open the file
run the iterations
close the file.

As discussed above in InspectorG4dget's solution - you can just follow that - except one catch that I see - he's again doing an open inside the with (the consequences of that are not known)

Here's the slightly better version - hopefully this does what you want.

```
mass_of_rider_kg = float(input('input mass of rider in kilograms:'))
mass_of_bike_kg = float(input('input mass of bike in kilograms:'))
velocity_in_ms = float(input('input velocity in meters per second:'))
coefficient_of_drafting = float(input('input coefficient of drafting:'))
with open('BikeOutput.txt', 'w') as myfile:
    a = mass_of_rider_kg
    while a < mass_of_rider_kg+20:
        a = a + 4
        pAir = .18*coefficient_of_drafting*(velocity_in_ms**3)  
        pRoll = .001*9.8*(a+mass_of_bike_kg)*velocity_in_ms
        pSec = pAir+pRoll
        print(pSec)
        myfile.write('data: %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f\n' %  ( a, mass_of_bike_kg, velocity_in_ms,coefficient_of_drafting, pSec))
```

Note using the with. you don't need to explicitly close the file. That's taken care of by with. Also, it is recommended to generate strings with formatting options as above rather than adding strings.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
with open('BikeOutput.txt','w') as myfile:
    while a < mass_of_rider_kg+20:
        a = a + 4
        pAir = .18*coefficient_of_drafting*(velocity_in_ms**3)  
        pRoll = .001*9.8*(a+mass_of_bike_kg)*velocity_in_ms
        pSec = pAir+pRoll
        print(a, '\t', pSec)
        myfile=open('BikeOutput.txt','w')
        myfile.write('data:' + str(a) + str(mass_of_bike_kg) + str(velocity_in_ms) + str(coefficient_of_drafting) + str(pSec) + "\n")
```

Comment: I didn't explain very well but im looking to print 5 lines of data. My while loop will give me 5 different values of 'a' and 5 different values of psec. I want to show a value of 'a' and the corresponding psec on a line. And then repeated for the other values on each of the 4 other lines.

Comment: @user2844776: check out the edit. It prints what you asked to screen

Answer (score 0):

In your write loop, your iterate is x. However, x is not used anywhere in your loop. You might want:

```
        myfile.write('data:' + str(x) + str(mass_of_bike_kg) + str(velocity_in_ms) + str(coefficient_of_drafting) + str(pSec) + "\n")
```